# JavaScript, retreive values into checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

My for loops are fine and I got the value for both `transportationOutput` and `trasportation2` and I want to check if both values are equal checked the right checkbox input, but it does not get into if condition and I do not know why, I try to replace the `==` to `===` but also it does not work

```js
trasportation = "car-train" //value from database
var trasportation2 = document.getElementsByName("transportation");
var transportationOutput = trasportation.split("-");


for (var i = 0; i < transportationOutput.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < trasportation2.length; j++) {
    if (trasportation2[j].value == transportationOutput[i]) {
      trasportation2[j].checked = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label>transportation</label>

<input type="checkbox" id="localTransportID" name="transportation" value="car"> car
<input type="checkbox" id="localTransportID" name="transportation" value="bus"> bus
<input type="checkbox" id="localTransportID" name="transportation" value="train"> train
<input type="checkbox" id="localTransportID" name="transportation" value="airplane"> airplane
```

Comment: Your code works just fine. Check a working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/chkdosy8/).

Comment: I have made a working snippet from your code, can you try and replicate your issue with this?

Comment: `id` need to be unique